# Hibernate merge two critera queries into a single query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following two queries, both which query the same table. One query I need all the results and the second I need a subset of results. In the end I need two list. Is there a way to share the first query with the second query.

```
    Criteria criteriaPrStatic = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class).add(Restrictions.eq("inactive", false));
    //Would like to use first query again and add the restrictions without having to query the table twice. 
    Criteria criteriaPrDynamic = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class).add(Restrictions.eq("inactive", false));
            criteriaPrDynamic.add(Restrictions.or(
                Restrictions.eq("creator", userInfo.getUser()),
                Restrictions.eq("authorizer", userInfo.getUser())
            ));

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("currentState"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());

    criteriaPrStatic.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteriaPrDynamic.setProjection(projectionList);
```

Comment: What do you mean by share ? have the code just once or have only one sql query that is issued to db ?

Comment: @Thierry, have one sql query issued to the db, but return one list with the restrictions and one without. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: Have you tried using filters? You can enable or disable it at any time. See this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html